# Certificates in PHP. Two way authentication ssl. Apache

Tags: php, apache, authentication, ssl, certificate

Context: production server with SSL installed. Running apache server. PHP.

Problem: for an specific url like (for example: www.domain.com/whatever/edit/*) I want to ask users to use their certificate in order to authenticate them for an specific task.

I have read that this way of authentication is called two-way authentication SSL. I don't know whether I am right or not.

What I have tried on server configuration is the following

```
<VirtualHost _default_:433>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/smartdataprotection/web/

        Options FollowSymLinks

        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews


LogLevel warn
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_access.log combined


SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile    /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/certificates/server.cer
SSLCertificateKeyFile /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/certificates/server.key
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars 

# Below for 2 way ssl
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 10
SSLCACertificateFile /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/certificates/ca.cer
```

What I would like to get is something similar to the following screen capture:
[image]

Thank you very much in advanced any help will be very welcome and highly appreciate.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're missing [`SSLCipherSuite` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslciphersuite) . In apache documentation:

> This complex directive uses a colon-separated cipher-spec string
>   consisting of OpenSSL cipher specifications to configure the Cipher
>   Suite the client is permitted to negotiate in the SSL handshake phase.

Also normally you want to login in a site with certificate in specific location not directly in www.yourdomain.com, for example in a button link with goes to `wwww.yourdomain.com/yourApp/loginCert` so you have to configure `<Location>` inside the `<VirtualHost>`.

Finally check the file indicated in the [`SSLCACertificateFile` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcacertificatefile), this file is a concatenation of CA certificates in a `PEM` format, which issues the certificates allowed to login in your site, if your certificate is not issued by one of the CAs inside this file they will be not showed up in the browser popup.

The configuration could looks like:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:433>
...
  <Location /yourApp/loginCert>

    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCACertificateFile conf/trustedCA.cer
    SSLVerifyClient required
    SSLVerifyDepth 10
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData +OptRenegotiate

  </Location>
```

Hope this helps,